# Неясная конструкция js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Ребята, учусь js, разбирая плагин dropzone.js. В ходе разбора натолкнулся на такую конструкцию:

```
{
        key: "emit",
        value: function emit(event) {
            this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};
            var callbacks = this._callbacks[event];

            if (callbacks) {
                for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len > 1 ? _len - 1 : 0), _key = 1; _key < _len; _key++) {
                    args[_key - 1] = arguments[_key];
                }

                for (var _iterator = callbacks, _isArray = true, _i = 0, _iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : _iterator[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
                    var _ref;

                    if (_isArray) {
                        if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
                        _ref = _iterator[_i++];
                    } else {
                        _i = _iterator.next();
                        if (_i.done) break;
                        _ref = _i.value;
                    }

                    var callback = _ref;

                    callback.apply(this, args);
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
```

Кто нибудь может сказать в чем смысл выражения:

```
_iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : _iterator[Symbol.iterator]() ?
```

Ведь согласно условию: _isArray = true, ветка else в выражении

```
  if (_isArray) {
        if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
               _ref = _iterator[_i++];
   } else {
        _i = _iterator.next();
        if (_i.done) break;
        _ref = _i.value;
   }
```

никогда не будет достигнута.

Comment: Возможно, раньше значение `_isArray` вычислялось, а не всегда равнялось `true`, а переписать код нормально (удалив более не нужные куски) не удосужились

Comment: Спасибо @Regent! Я подумал возможно это какой-то задел на будущее, т.к выражение `Symbol.iterator` доступен, если не ошибаюсь в ECMAScript2015 т.е расчитан на более современные браузеры...

Comment: Судя по всему, данный код является продуктом сборки, и возможно эта часть кода была добавлена сборщиком, а какой был исходник пока не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по предоставленному коду, речь идет про [`github`](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone).

Однако на самом деле разработка ведется на [`gitlab`](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone), о чем указано в `readme`:

> This is no longer the official repository for Dropzone. I have switched to gitlab.com as the primary location to continue development.

---

#### Что на самом деле происходит в коде?

Указанные строки находятся в месте объявления класса [`Emitter`](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.js#L46), а конкретнее в реализации метода [`emit`](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.js#L60)

Если пройти на [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.js#L45) увидим простой метод:

```
emit(event, ...args) {
    this._callbacks = this._callbacks || {};
    let callbacks = this._callbacks[event];

    if (callbacks) {
      for (let callback of callbacks) {
        callback.apply(this, args);
      }
    }

    return this;
}
```

Из которого явно видно, что данный код является реализацией [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) после сборки.

Comment: Спасибо большое @Grundy! Очень исчерпывающий ответ. Вы открыли мне новый горизонт анализа.

Comment: Осталось понять какого черта цикл for-of компилируется в такую чушь...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну он ж на итерабельные объекты рассчитан, то есть у которых есть метод с именем `Symbol.iterator` и просто для массивов сделали типа оптимизации, что не нужно вызывать итератор, а просто в `for`. Конечно есть дальнейший простор для оптимизаций, и возможно какой-нить минификатор бы это все и выкинул как ненужное, но в общем случае код вполне норм, если б конечно `isArray` - не статично задавалось.

Comment: @Grundy так ведь именно это и смущает. Откуда оно знает, что callbacks - массив?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, единственный вариант - это из-за [строки в on](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.js#L38): `this._callbacks[event] = [];` сборщик считает массивов, но как-то не совсем уверенно, раз не убирает ненужное, либо у него просто шаблон подстановки такой стандартные, и при сборке просто какие-то из параметров этого шаблона подставляются

Comment: @Grundy а какой сборщик может такое вытворять? Типа babel?

Comment: @Андрей, там бабель и используется и грунт

Comment: @Grundy Thanks!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, кстати на сайте бабеля немного попробовал, там в этой строчке: `_isArray = Array.isArray(_iterator),` то есть все логично

Comment: @Grundy угу, и у меня тоже так получалось. Более того, в исходниках бабеля там стоит строго проверка `Array.isArray` без каких бы то ни было замен. Так что откуда взялся true - неясно...